# Correct way to update related field for 1-to-many relation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Issuer has as a related field KeyEntity. My code works, but I think that there must be a better way to update the related field other than loading entities from database.
There should be something wrong in ViewModeling and templating... Thanks in advance.

OpViewModel

```cs
public class OpViewModel
{   
    public Connect.Models.Issuer Issuer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> KeyEntities { get; set; }

    public OpViewModel() { } 
    public OpViewModel(Connect.Models.Issuer issuer, 
                        IEnumerable<Jose.Models.KeyEntity> key_entities)
    {   
        this.Issuer = issuer;
        this.KeyEntities = key_entities.Select(k =>
                        new SelectListItem()
                        {   
                            Selected = (k.Id == issuer.KeyEntity.Id),
                            Text = k.Id.ToString(),
                            Value = k.Id.ToString()
                        }); 
    }   
}
```

Op/Edit.chtml(Razor)

```cs
@model AdConnect.Models.OpViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Issuer.KeyEntity.Id,
                                Model.KeyEntities)
    </div>

}
```

OpController

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Models.OpViewModel obj)
    {   
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            //  This works for most data fields of Issuer, but KeyEntity's Id 
            //  (dbo.Issuers.KeyEntity_Id) is not updated.
            //
            //  ctx.Entry(obj.Issuer).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified

            //  So load Issuer and KeyEntity from the database and update.

            var issuer = ctx.Issuers.Find(obj.Issuer.Id);
            if (obj.Issuer.KeyEntity != null)
            {   
                 issuer.KeyEntity =
                    ctx.KeyEntities.Find(obj.Issuer.KeyEntity.Id);
            }   
            ctx.Entry(issuer).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj.Issuer);

            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a bit around how navigation properties work. EF can automatically populate them so you aren't doing it in the constructor of the object.

Have a read of my article on nav properties [here](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/07/entity-framework-navigation-property.html).

Also in terms of your controller update code the normal path for an update like this is: Load, Modify, Save.

ie

```
var issuer = ctx.Issuers.Include(i=>i.KeyEntity).SingleOrDefault(i=>i.Id == obj.Issuer.Id);
issuer.Whatever = obj.Issuer.Whatever; //note prehaps you want something like CopyMatchinProperties here
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you Luke very much. Your article is quite fine to newbie like me. But I suppose there must be better way for providing a ViewModel and better template syntax for selection.  Other fields than KeyEntity are updated in a single line `ctx.Entry(obj.Issuer).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified`, but not for KeyEntity. That's a question.

Comment: Hi Hideki, I normally completely separate my data and view models which means that I don't actually get a data model back from my view at all. This is fairly common practice as its a method of abstracting two distinct peices of your application. I would recommend further reading about this method and why its important. http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/ToModelOrViewModel, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264009/asp-net-mvc-how-to-separate-view-models-from-db-models

Comment: However if you do want to keep sending the data models all the way to your view I think you will also need to set the modified state on all of the other entities your model touches. (for example your KeyEntity in the example you describe).

Comment: Thank you again Luke. I'll try that later because this week has just finished now. :-)

Comment: Totally my misconception. MVC EF never loads exiting model data from data store like Django(Python framework) ModelForm does.  Programmers have to write code to load existing model data, update fields which have been modified and save that back to data store.  Anyway, thank you very much, Luke.